# Ngtaginput get back all tags in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.js ngTagsInput plugin 
http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos  which is working fine 
Now when i click i get some  tags like 
**tag1, tag2, tag3,**
I removed tag2

Can we get back tag2 again using function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you remove a tag, you can catch the event using `onTagRemove`, and then later add it back using ngModel

For instance (adapt to your needs):

```
<tags-input ng-model="tagsModel" on-tag-removed="removedTags.push($tag)" >
```

And your fucntion to put it back:

```
$scope.tagsModel = [];

$scope.putTagBack = function() {
  $scope.tagsModel.push( $scope.removedTags.pop() );
}
```

PS: not sure if `$tag` is an object or a string. If it is a string you need to push back `{text: t.pop() }` instead of `t.pop()`where `t` is `$scope.removedTags`.

Comment: i am using this 

<tags-input ng-model="moveArticle.categoryNames" on-tag-removed="moveArticle.removedCategory.push($tag)" >


and on Controller 


 $scope.tagsModel.push($scope.moveArticle.removedCategory.pop());

Comment: giving me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Well you need to adapt my variables names. Since your `ngModel` is moveArticle.categoryNames, you should replace the line by `moveArticle.categoryNames.push( $scope.moveArticle.removedCategory.pop() )`. I just gave you the idea of the solution, you need to think about it.